# Find at least one needle in a haystack string, where an array of needles is supplied

Tags: php, arrays, string, search

I have a function that takes a string (the haystack) and an array of strings (the needles) and returns `true` if at least one needle is a substring of the haystack. It didn't take much time or effort to write it, but I'm wondering if there's a PHP function that already does this.

```
function strstr_array_needle($haystack, $arrayNeedles){
    foreach($arrayNeedles as $needle){
        if(strstr($haystack, $needle)) return true;
    }
    return false;    
}
```

Comment: change `strstr($haystack, $needle)` to `strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false`...

Comment: The PHP documentation has an explicit note stating that `strstr()` should not be used to confirm the existence of a substring (for performance reasons, it is always more ideal to use `strpos()` for such an operation).

Answer (score 9):

just a suggestion...

```
function array_strpos($haystack, $needles)
{
    foreach($needles as $needle)
        if(strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, any particular reason to use strpos rather than strstr?

Comment: @RichardLivingston, Hi, well you should, because strstr returns part of the string (also this behavior is different with PHP5.3), while strpos returns position (if found) or false (if not found), so that is possibly faster. From the documents `If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead.`. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There's no single function that behaves as `strstr_array_needle` (the name is misleading; I'd expect it to return a substring of `$haystack`). There are other functions that could be used instead of a loop, but they don't have benefits and take more time. For example:

```
# iterates over entire array, though stops checking once a match is found
array_reduce($needles, 
    function($found, $needle) use ($haystack) {
        return $found || (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false);
    }, 
    false);

# iterates over entire array and checks each needle, even if one is already found
(bool)array_filter($needles,
    function($needle) use ($haystack) {
        return strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tested and working function:

```
<?php
function strpos_array($haystack, $needles, $offset = 0) {
    if (is_array($needles)) {
        foreach ($needles as $needle) {
            $pos = strpos_array($haystack, $needle);
            if ($pos !== false) {
                return $pos;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return strpos($haystack, $needles, $offset);
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than using an `if` block, simply cast the `$needles` as an array in the `foreach()` signature: `foreach ((array) $needles as $needle) {`  ...if you aren't going to apply type declarations to your function parameters.

Comment: Oh, now I see that you are offering a recursive solution -- that might have been a good idea to mention when describing your script.  I don't think the asker or most researchers will need to traverse an indeterminant number of levels in the needles array.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you need to return a boolean result or the first encountered match, use a breakable loop to eliminate useless cycles. If you are using an outdated/unsupported version of PHP, replace `str_contains()` with a `strpos() !== false` check.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7LrSm))

```
function findANeedle(string $haystack, array $needles) {
    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
        if (str_contains($haystack, $needle)) {
            return $needle;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function hasANeedle(string $haystack, array $needles): bool {
    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
        if (str_contains($haystack, $needle)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$haystack = 'food fighters';
$needles = ['bar', 'foo'];

var_export(findANeedle($haystack, $needles));
echo "\n--\n";
var_export(hasANeedle($haystack, $needles));
```

Output:

```
'foo'
--
true
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're wanting to do but I think `in_array()` could help you do what you're looking for.

```
$needleArray = array(1, 2, 3);  // the values we want to get from
$outputArray = array( ... );    // the values to search for

foreach ($outputArray as $value) {
    if (in_array($value, $needleArray)) {
        // do what you want to do...the $value exists in $needleArray
    }
}
```

Comment: `in_array` only supports equality comparisons (`==` and `===`). Richard's function uses substring comparison.

Comment: This script does not perform a substring search as required by the asker.

Answer (score -1):

If you are just trying to determine which needles exist in the haystack, I suggest the `array_intersect` function.

Documentation from the PHP.net website

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>

The above example will output:
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```

Basically, this will result in an array that shows all values that appear in both arrays. In your case, your code is returning true if any needle is found. The following code will do this using the `array_intersect` function, though if this is any simpler than Charles answer is debatable.

```
if(sizeof(array_intersect($hackstack, $arrayNeedles)) > 0) 
    return true; 
else 
    return false;
```

Again, I am not sure exactly what your code is trying to do, other than return true if any needle exists. If you can provide some context on what you want to achieve, there may be a better way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The haystack is not an array.